# How to server mute everyone in a discord call (specify the channel)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Currently I am using this code to server mute everyone in the call I am in,

```
bot.on('message', message => {
if (message.content === '!vcmute') {
    const members = message.member.voice.channel.members;
    members.forEach(member => {
        member.voice.setMute(true);
    });
}
```

});

Is there a way to modify the code (I'm guessing by adding arguments) to specify WHICH vc I would like to mute? I am new to coding so I honestly have no clue how arguments work

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify and get the correct (voice) channel you want to mute the users in:

```
bot.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content.startsWith('!vcmute')) {

        let person = 0 //make sure person always has a value

        const messageArray = message.content.split(' ') //split content on every space into array
        const targetChannel = messageArray[1] //first item from messageArray is the command input, second item the channelid
        const voiceChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.get(targetChannel)//get channel information by ID

        if (voiceChannel.type != "voice") return message.channel.send("This id does not belong to a voice channel"); //return if channel is not a voicechannel

        voiceChannel.members.forEach(member => {
            person = message.guild.members.cache.get(member.id);
            person.voice.setMute(true);
        });
    }
});
```

Note that you will have to do **!vcmute [channelID]** to mute everyone in the voice channel.

Comment: Is there a way i can do this without using channel id and not name?

Comment: @Shreyas007 You could also use the name, but in general this leads to a lot of false positives. For example: If you have a textchannel named general and a voicechannel named general, it will often get the textchannel, because it's above the voicechannel. Therefor it's not reliable


This is the code to look for channelname
`message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name.toLowerCase() == targetChannel.toLowerCase())`

Comment: Is there a way to exempt certain users from being muted? @Fluxpuck

Comment: @Shreyas007 yes, before muting the people, you could go check if an array with excluded user ids does not includes the user and mute the person.

Answer (score 0):

Make an array including userids from users that should not get muted.
Check if the array does not include the member.id, if it doesn't, mute the person.

```
  voiceChannel.members.forEach(member => {
    person = message.guild.members.cache.get(member.id);
    let excludedUsers = ['854527257592525252', '58437594735942358345']
    if (!excludedUsers.include(member.id)) {
        person.voice.setMute(true);
    }
  });
```